# constexpr base class member set by derived class

Tags: c++, constexpr

I want to do something like this:

```
// a base class for a family of devices
class foobar_base()
{
    int _n;

public:

    foo_base(int num_of_things) : _n(num_of_things){}

    // I would like to use this from derived classes, where
    // constants are required, such as array sizes...
    constexpr int num_of_things() const {return _n;}


};

// a specific device that has 5 things
class foo: public foobar_base
{
public:
    // foo has 5 things
    foo():foo_base(5){}
};

// a specific device that has 10 things
class bar: public foobar_base
{
public:
    // bar has 10 things
    bar():foo_base(10){}
};


// some class or code that wants to use the family of devices
// represented by the base class...
class foobar_user()
{
    shared_ptr<foobar_base> f(new foo())

    // I want this to have the number of things that foo has
    int array_for_foo_things[f->num_of_things()];

    shared_ptr<foobar_base> b(new bar())

    // and this to have the number of things that bar has
    int array_for_bar_things[b->num_of_things()];

};
```

What I'm trying to do is use information coming from the derived classes via a base class pointer, where constants are required, as in the line:

```
    int array_for_foo_things[f->num_of_things()];
```

Obviously, I can use vectors instead of arrays as a workaround, but the desire is to find a way to get a constexpr from a base class pointer that is set from the derived classes of the base class.

Comment: A template as base class maybe?

Comment: dont forget semicolons after classes :D

Comment: Ultimately, I hold the shared pointers in a vector.  If there is a way to hold the shared pointers with varying template arguments, I'm in business, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: If you just correct your syntactic errors in your code, then your code will compile just fine.
Your user is using a derived class which is using a member of its base class, nothing illegal here as far as i can see. Except maybe you want your pointers to be of the derived class.

Comment: I want to end up with vector<foobar_base> to hold a mixture of the derived classes.  This seems to break all of the solutions I can come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the idea of `user0042`, you mean something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// a base class for a family of devices
template<int _N>
class foobar_base
{
    // int _n;

public:

    foobar_base() {}

    // I would like to use this from derived classes, where
    // constants are required, such as array sizes...
    constexpr int num_of_things() const {return _N;}
};

// a specific device that has 5 things
class foo: public foobar_base<5>
{
public:
    // foo has 5 things
    foo() {}
};

// a specific device that has 10 things
class bar: public foobar_base<10>
{
public:
    // bar has 10 things
    bar(){}
};


// some class or code that wants to use the family of devices
// represented by the base class...
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<foobar_base<5>> f(new foo());

    // I want this to have the number of things that foo has
    int array_for_foo_things[f->num_of_things()];

    std::shared_ptr<foobar_base<10>> b(new bar());

    // and this to have the number of things that bar has
    int array_for_bar_things[b->num_of_things()];

    std::cout<<"foo: "<<sizeof(array_for_foo_things)/sizeof(int)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"bar: "<<sizeof(array_for_bar_things)/sizeof(int)<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: There is a detail that I left out of my original post (for clarity)...  I want to hold the shared pointers in a vector.  I can't figure out how to create a vector of the base class when the base class has a template argument.

Comment: In addition to that, the user shouldn't have to know that foo has 5 things (to know to make it a foobar_base<5>, for example).  I want the information to originate from the derived classes in a way that is exposed to the user, not that the user has to know.

Comment: use `std::shared_ptr<foo>` and `std::shared_ptr<bar>`. But if you look for storing both in the same array, you should know that the array cannot store different type. If you design them with the same type, then `constexpr` cannot differentiate between them.